# Ascertaining the highest power of 2 for a given integer

Tags: java, debugging

When I run this method with n = 64, it gives me x = 64, but instead of running the if statement it runs the else statement. The actual answer needs to be 32, but it returns 64.

```
/**
 * Complete the method to find the largest power of 2 less than the given number
 * Use a loop
 */

public class MathUtil {
  public int largestPowerOf2(int n) {
    // TODO: implement this method.
    int i = 0;
    while(n > 1) {
      n = n / 2;
      i ++;
    }
    System.out.printf("i = %d\n" , i);
    int x = (int)Math.pow(2,i);
    System.out.println(x);
    if(x == n) {
      return (int)Math.pow(2,i - 1);
    } else {
      return (int)Math.pow(2, i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Step through the code as it executes and examine the runtime values and behavior.

Comment: Hint: What value does `n` have when the if statement is executed?  When you've answered that question, you'll know why the code is not working.  Cheers :)

Comment: How do you think `if(x == n)` will execute when you are continuously doing `n = n / 2;` in your while loop?

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong here. It will not work where the integer is already a power of 2. It's a boundary problem. You need to handle that boundary better in your logic.

Comment: Are you looking for `Integer.highestOneBit(n - 1)`?

Comment: I need to remember that value of n is constantly changing .I should use another variable to store value of n before while loop.

Comment: Did any of the answers below satisfy your question?

Comment: A smart way would be to use something on the lines of x & ~x. You can then map the position of the 1 bit to yield the answer. Will work for 2's complement int.

Answer (score 0):

multiply a test int times 2 until you get a number that is not less than your target then return the previous number

```
public int largestPowerOf2(int n){
    int mul = 1;
    int lastWorkingSolution = 0;
    while(true){
        if(mul >= n)
            return lastWorkingSolution;
        else{
            lastWorkingSolution=mul;
            mul*=2; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple way of doing the same thing. Simply loop through the powers of 2 until you hit one that is greater than or equal to n. Then, just subtract 1 from the power to get the last working example and return that powered value.

```
private static int largestPowerOf2(int n) {
    int power = 1;
    int value = (int)Math.pow(2, power);
    while (value < n) {
        power++;
        value = (int)Math.pow(2, power);
    }

    power--;

    return (int)Math.pow(2, power);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public int largestPowerOf2(int n){

    return Integer.highestOneBit(n-1);

}
```